# Promise.all do not wait all promises to resolve

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I need to get data in parallel, and then calculate with them simultaneously, with Node.js.

So I use promise.all, but it behaves strange. When I launch it the first time, the calculations are longer and it fails just after the first promise has resolved, even if the others succeed.
When I launch it the second time, it's faster because all data are stored in the database, so it succeeds.
I really don't understand. Here is my code :

```
var Promise = require('promise');
/* The list of objects */
var ingrd_list = JSON.parse(req.body.ingrd_list);
/* func.addFood is my function to apply on. It takes a callback parameter as last parameter */
var pAddFood = Promise.denodeify(func.addFood);
var pArray = [];

ingrd_list.forEach(function(ingrd){
    var my_p = pAddFood(ingrd);
    pArray.push(my_p);
    });

Promise.all(pArray).then(function(){
    console.log("success !");
    })
    .catch(function(){
            console.log("failure !");
    });
```

I have defined the addFood function in an other file, like this :

```
exports.addFood = function(ingrd, cb){
        /* Some code */
    cb(data.id);
});
```

I want to apply this function, so I tried to make it "denodeify-compatible".
But it doesn't work as expected. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: what do you mean by failure? Does it give any errors?

Comment: It sounds like one of the `addFood` timed out, threw an error and caused a `Promise` to reject. This will result in `Promise.all` rejecting immediately (`Promise.all` rejects if any promise rejects).

Comment: I mean that the other promises are rejected, even if they don't have finish to run.

Comment: If one of the promises fail, Promise.all will fail

Comment: But there is no timer (unless maybe inside the promise object), and the other **addFood* functions terminate normally, by calling the callback function.

Comment: `.catch(function(err){
            console.error(err);
    });` do this and see what happens

Comment: `.catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });` displays the parameter passed to the callback function of the first promise that completes (so just before considering all other promises as rejected)

Comment: Check the answer, you're not calling the callback correctly.

Comment: Actually, I wonder if I should not have 2 callback functions : One for resolved, and one for rejected. But I don't know how to implement it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `denodeify` expect your callback to be called in a standard way, that is `callback(err, data)`

but you are calling you callback with `callback(data)`, so it is putting your promise in a rejected state, because it thinks that you data is in fact the error, thus `Promise.all` fails

To fix that you should modify you `addFood` function to call the callback like this `cb(undefined, data.id);`

ps: you can look for "node style callback" if you want more detailed information about this callback style

Comment: Works great ! Thanks !